# Cast Base Class | typescript

Tags: typescript, annotations

```js
class Base {}
class Child extends Base {}

interface BaseCtor {
    new (): Base;
}

let baseCtor: BaseCtor = Base; // works fine
let ChildCtor: BaseCtor = Child; // complains neither overlaps
```

considering the previous code, I want to annotate the constructor of a class that extends an other. Any thing I'm gettin wrong here? Or should it be done in an other way?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the issue](https://tsplay.dev/mLrp4w).  Could you double check that this is a [mre]?

Comment: I do not get an error with this either, locally or in ts playground.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8C+BYAUKSMDCAFgJYgAm0CAHgC4IB2pM8ESaWWRdtATgGZjAkzBHmoB7biizQZ0OggDu0ABQBKAFxxEAbiwZMWEAmrQARolETNwy5IC8WltugB6F9AUSA1jF6cEhsbQwMRkttYW4vbQhCSkzm7BYgC2AA7gnDDyRNQECJJiAG754KkQ7JhAA